# After update/delete files of Static Website in Azure it still shows the old

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a `Static Website` in an `Azure Blob Storage`.
I update my files by using the `Release Pipelines` in `Azure DevOps`.

I've been looking to the files by going in the portal and open the `Editor(Preview)`, in there it shows that my files were updated well.

Now the problem is that when I go to this Static Website in the browser it does not update the content. So I tried to delete all my browser history/cache etc.
Also this did nothing with the view when browsing to the Static Website.

I tried to delete all the files from the Static Website('Also delete blob snapshots' enabled), they were all deleted from the Static Website.

But also this did nothing when going to the Static Website in the browser.

So I did google if someone already got this problem, but without success.
Also I tried to find if there was a button to restart the Static Website/Azure Blob Storage. But also without success.

I hope someone here can help me with this problem.

---

Extra info

- Content is a build of a React App
- I have made a custom domain so it could redirect to my own DNS

---

Bonus question:

Is there a way to delete files within the Azure Pipelines?

Comment: Can you share link to your website?

Comment: @GauravMantri cuz of privacy rules of the company I may not share the link. Do you maybe have some suggestions?

Comment: To delete files via Azure Pipelines I use the AzureCLI task. There you can define an inline script with az storage blob delete-batch (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_delete_batch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can see updated files in azure storage, they are most likely updated. Something might be caching the files. You can check in chrome dev tools if the files are getting cached by browser.

Easiest way to auto update the cached files is adding a cache header such 'max-age' which forces the cache to be refreshed after an interval has passed.

Azure storage provides an option to set max-age header.
For always getting data from storage and not using cache, set max-age to - 1

You can refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-manage-expiration-of-blob-content#azure-storage-explorer for steps to do it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will this not be a problem for the serviceworker.js?

Comment: Also, on an other machine where I never addressed to this link it shows the old files

Comment: Seems like static website automatically takes care of cache-control. I tried a hello world app in static website and it was reflecting immediately. Can you try modifying index file from Editor(preview) and see if it reflects?

Comment: this did work indeed. But this ectually is a problem. Because my index.html will mostly not change at all

Comment: How about having some metadata in your index like last build date?  `<meta name = "revised" content = "3/7/2014" />` I am pretty sure you can automate it and it will help you track your changes

Comment: I never knew this meta key did exist. I'll try this as well. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

One common problem is [Azure Content Delivery Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-overview). The CDN stores your static files and serves them to browsers from a globally distributed network. This is great for performance, but CDN can continue serving old content after an update.

[image: Azure CDN]

To get around this, in Azure Portal, browse to your "storage account", and then look for "Azure CDN" under "Security + Networking".

[image: Azure Portal Menu]

Next click on your host name and you will be presented with "purge" button. After you purge the CDN, the new content will be available immediately (you may have to refresh your web browser).

Answer (score 0):

Is the option **CacheControl still up to date?** I have no way to find this option via Azure Storage Explorer. I am registered for this Azure subscription in the owner role. My deployment also takes place via Azure DevOps Pipelines, but my static website does not change. If I check the files via Storage Explorer (preview) in my Azure Portal, everything is up to date. Unfortunately I cannot find the setting described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-manage-expiration-of-blob-content#azure-storage-explorer).

Also my timestamp of the file was updated. It's not a local cache problem, since I am testing the static site from new devices as well.

Because I use an **CDN Endpoint** for my **custom domain**, I tried the following optimization. I will check the adjustment if this currently has an effect

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see, you can set "Bypass cache"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the files are updated in the blob endpoint but not in the website endpoint.

If you delete your local cache you can be sure that its not a local problem.

For me it worked after ~20-30 minutes of waiting. This means it is really related to chaching, like others pointed out. But I noticed that not all files were updated at the same time.

If you have rapid changing content on your website you may want to use "max-age = -1" on your blob headers or overwrite the max-age with caching rules.